# MongoDB : FindOne() return null but the document exist Discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I am creating a giveaway system, I use mongo DB with the node module `mongoose` to store the giveaway data using this code :

```
await DB.create({
          GuildID: interaction.guild.id,
          MessageID: message.id,
          ChannelID: interaction.channel.id,
          EndTime: formattedDuration,
          Ended: false,
          HostedBy: interaction.user.id,
          Prize: prize,
          Winners: winners,
          Paused: false,
          Entered: [],
        })
```

it create the doc successfully in the database

in a separated command I use this code to get the giveaway data

also I am sure that the Message ID given is correct

```
          const data = await DB.findOne({
            GuildID: interaction.guild.id,
            MessageID: messageId
          });
          console.log(data);
```

But it return null

I tried

```
findById()
```

but the same it return null

I am using discord.js v14.7.1 & mongoose v6.7.5 & node v18.12.1

Comment: What happens if you do `const data = await DB.find({});`? If that returns documents, it would prove that the collection does indeed contain documents. Then you can try `const matchingDocuments = data.find(doc => doc.GuildID === interaction.guild.id && doc.MessageID === messageId);`. If that returns a document, it would prove that there is a matching document in the collection. If either of those things doesn't happen, it will be a great clue for you.

Comment: The data return the document but the matchingDocuments return undefined @Aurast

Comment: Sounds like the collection doesn't contain any documents that match your search criteria.

Comment: @Aurast i double checked and it's contain the document

Comment: But the document doesn't match your search criteria, according to the testing you just did. You should have enough information now to investigate why.

Comment: @Aurast i am sure it matches the search

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wrap the messageId in ObjectId(messageId) if this is a ObjectId in the document

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
const data = await DB.findOne({
            GuildID: interaction.guild.id,
            MessageID: ObjectId(messageId)
          });
          console.log(data);
```

Comment: the messageId is just a string